# Azure Service Fabric autoscaling of stateful services

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-autoscaling) on autoscaling in Service Fabric. Now I am wondering about how this works with stateful services. It is possible to add more partitions but what about redistributing the data?

Example:

2 Partitions with range 0-99
Due to autoscaling we get a 3rd partition, what happens with data in partition 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition scheme & range you have described cannot be autoscaled.

- Named partition scheme must be used for the service.
- Partition names must be consecutive integer numbers, like "0", "1", ... First
  partition name must be "0".

Data in partition 1 & 2 would be unchanged in the event of a partition being added if the above conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So this would mean me as a developer would be responsible for redistributing data? In this case it kind of gets non trivial...

Comment: Yes, this is always the case in Stateful Services, they are essentially unaware of the data in themselves, they just replicate data they own out to secondaries. Usually you will have a service higher upstream that understands the partitioning logic and can decide where to post the downstream data to - ie which partition. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @KnowHoper that means the 'old' partition algorithm may not be anymore consistent (e.g. hash(ID).modulo(2)) as soon as a new, third partition is added on the fly? So Helikaon is right, that another service would have to FIRST re-shuffle data..